# 3G USB dongles not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, usb, 18.04, usb-modem

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my system, It's not recognizing my iBall 3.5G USB modem,
Which was working fine in the previous version (Ubuntu 16.04)

On Ubuntu 14.04 I was able to access **Network Connections** window, But in the newer version(Ubuntu 18.04) I can't find that anymore

[image]

How to solve this!